# Basic “filtering” in digital communications

Tags: filters, filter-design, digital-communications, linear-systems, digital-filters

I am completely stuck on solving some problems for my digital communications class. Junior level undergrad class, so fairly basic. I have been searching around all day for related articles etc but can't seem to find any that are helpful. Any help would be much appreciated. [Here are the three questions](http://prntscr.com/6njdcj):

[image]
[image]

For the coefficients my initial hunch is just to make c2 and c3 = 0, which would leave $\hat{y}[1] = y[1]$. My other attempt is to create a system of equations so the $x[2]$ terms are cancelled and the $x[1]$ terms are the only ones left over, but this system proves difficult to me and I am left with a mess of noise. For some reason I can only get two equations with three unknowns.

$$c_3= -3 c_2 \\
c_1 + \frac13  c_2 + \frac14 c_3 = 1$$
  where $c_1,c_2,c_3$ are constants.

Sorry for my terrible formatting. I believe I completed the first question correctly, here was my process.

[image]

Moving on to question 2, for part A I'm fairly sure it is what I was attempting to do before so I got c3=-3 * c2

for part b, I am stuck again because my brain keeps going back to the idea that I should just make c2 and c3 both 0, because it appears to me our goal is to make x[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cfut.png) recoverable.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a homework question with no demonstrated attempt at a solution.

Comment: I understand your point, but I don't really understand the question so any "attempt" I make won't even be in the right direction. If you could at least give me a hint as to how to get started (assuming you know how to do it), I would be very appreciative. Thanks

Comment: @KevinDahm any attempt so long as its reasonable will help members of this site guide you. They may not just tell you answer. There is value in discovering the answer yourself. I suggest you your chapter on this topic, and then TRY to answer. Who cares if its wrong. Do what you THINK is the correct way. Give some explanation why you are doing certain things. When you have put some effort, members of this site will spend their time to help you.

Comment: Alright, sorry I'm new here. I edited the question to include my naive attempts to question 1, part a.

Comment: Cross-posted to [engineering](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2259/basic-filtering-in-digital-communications) and [electrical engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/162463/basic-filtering-in-digital-communications)

Comment: Are you by any chance taking ECE 361 at the University of Illinois at Urbana-Champaign this semester?

Comment: Just to complete the record, this instructor of ECE 361 at the University of Illinois at Urbana-Champaign confirmed that this question _is_ from homework assigned in the course. The homework submission deadline has passed and so if anyone wants to take a whack at it, at least the OP will not be getting an unfair advantage over his fellow-students

Comment: In fact, the OP posted the same question on three different SE sites, and the one above is here because it was _migrated_ from electronics.SE to dsp.SE. As Jim Clay's comment points out, we already have our own version, thank you very much. Perhaps the moderators can merge the two questions.....

Comment: @DilipSarwate Done! As much as is possible.